# Drupal7 site slider not being Displayed

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on Drupal 7, while working suddenly got this error:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/mycaze/public_html/university/sites/all/modules/mimemail/includes/mimemail.mail.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/local/altphp/lib/php') in /home/mycaze/public_html/university/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3160"

and the slider is not displayed in other browsers like Mozilla, also CSS problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first fix this error. Easiest way is to disable mimemail module. Then check for Javascript errors in browser's console.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your guidance, but i haven't installed mimemail module. Now how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Remove whole folder /home/mycaze/public_html/university/sites/all/modules/mimemail/